# after upgrade to gcc9.3 linking segfaults in lto-wrapper but LTO is disabled

Tags: gcc, arm, lto

I just upgraded gcc form 7.5 to 9.3 and started to have gcc linker segfaults - but only on armv7 target (the same all sources are building/linking OK for aarch64/x86_64 targets).

Segfault is in lto-wrapper - but I disabled LTO so I'm a bit confused....

here is gcc linking output:

```
    armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -v -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/qt5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/qt5/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,libmythtv-32.so.32 -o libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0 obj/cc.o obj/vbi.o obj/lang.o obj/recordinginfo.o obj/dbcheck.o obj/videodbcheck.o obj/tvremoteutil.o obj/tv.o obj/jobqueue.o obj/recordingprofile.o obj/remoteencoder.o obj/videosource.o obj/cardutil.o obj/sourceutil.o obj/videometadatautil.o obj/vbi608extractor.o obj/cc608decoder.o obj/cc608reader.o obj/cc708decoder.o obj/cc708reader.o obj/cc708window.o obj/subtitlereader.o obj/scheduledrecording.o obj/signalmonitorvalue.o obj/livetvchain.o obj/playgroup.o obj/channelsettings.o obj/previewgenerator.o obj/previewgeneratorqueue.o obj/transporteditor.o obj/channelgroup.o obj/recordingrule.o obj/mythsystemevent.o obj/mythmediabuffer.o obj/mythavformatbuffer.o obj/mythfilebuffer.o obj/mythstreamingbuffer.o obj/mythinteractivebuffer.o obj/mythopticalbuffer.o obj/metadataimagehelper.o obj/mythframe.o obj/mythavutil.o obj/recordingfile.o obj/diseqc.o obj/diseqcsettings.o obj/mythmediawriter.o obj/mythavformatwriter.o obj/mythfifowriter.o obj/teletextdecoder.o obj/teletextreader.o obj/vbilut.o obj/tspacket.o obj/pespacket.o obj/mpegtables.o obj/atsctables.o obj/dvbtables.o obj/premieretables.o obj/sctetables.o obj/mpegstreamdata.o obj/atscstreamdata.o obj/dvbstreamdata.o obj/scanstreamdata.o obj/mpegdescriptors.o obj/atscdescriptors.o obj/dvbdescriptors.o obj/sctedescriptors.o obj/splicedescriptors.o obj/dishdescriptors.o obj/premieredescriptors.o obj/atsc_huffman.o obj/freesat_huffman.o obj/iso6937tables.o obj/H264Parser.o obj/tablestatus.o obj/tsstreamdata.o obj/frequencies.o obj/frequencytables.o obj/channelutil.o obj/channelinfo.o obj/dtvmultiplex.o obj/dtvconfparser.o obj/dtvconfparserhelpers.o obj/scaninfo.o obj/channelimporter.o obj/iptvchannelfetcher.o obj/srtwriter.o obj/mythdvdbuffer.o obj/mythdvdcontext.o obj/mythdvdinfo.o obj/mythdvdstream.o obj/mythdvdplayer.o obj/mythdvddecoder.o obj/mythbdiowrapper.o obj/mythbdbuffer.o obj/mythbdinfo.o obj/mythbdoverlay.o obj/mythbdplayer.o obj/mythbddecoder.o obj/mythbdoverlayscreen.o obj/httplivestream.o obj/httplivestreambuffer.o obj/m3u.o obj/profilegroup.o obj/tv_play.o obj/mythplayer.o obj/audioplayer.o obj/mythccextractorplayer.o obj/teletextextractorreader.o obj/playercontext.o obj/tv_play_win.o obj/deletemap.o obj/mythcommflagplayer.o obj/commbreakmap.o obj/tvbrowsehelper.o obj/netstream.o obj/mythiowrapper.o obj/textsubtitleparser.o obj/xine_demux_sputext.o obj/decoderbase.o obj/nuppeldecoder.o obj/avformatdecoder.o obj/privatedecoder.o obj/mythcodeccontext.o obj/osd.o obj/teletextscreen.o obj/subtitlescreen.o obj/interactivescreen.o obj/mythvideoout.o obj/mythvideooutnull.o obj/videobuffers.o obj/jitterometer.o obj/videodisplayprofile.o obj/mythcodecid.o obj/videooutwindow.o obj/videocolourspace.o obj/videovisual.o obj/mythdeinterlacer.o obj/mythvaapicontext.o obj/mythdrmprimecontext.o obj/mythopenglvideo.o obj/mythvideooutopengl.o obj/mythopenglinterop.o obj/mythvideotexture.o obj/mythopengltonemap.o obj/mythvaapiinterop.o obj/mythvaapiglxinterop.o obj/mythdrmprimeinterop.o obj/mythegldmabuf.o obj/mythvaapidrminterop.o obj/filters.o obj/goom_core.o obj/graphic.o obj/tentacle3d.o obj/ifs.o obj/ifs_display.o obj/lines.o obj/surf3d.o obj/zoom_filter_mmx.o obj/zoom_filter_xmmx.o obj/videovisualgoom.o obj/DetectLetterbox.o obj/mythairplayserver.o obj/mythraopdevice.o obj/mythraopconnection.o obj/dsmcc.o obj/dsmcccache.o obj/dsmccbiop.o obj/dsmccobjcarousel.o obj/mhegic.o obj/interactivetv.o obj/mhi.o obj/channelbase.o obj/dtvchannel.o obj/signalmonitor.o obj/dtvsignalmonitor.o obj/inputinfo.o obj/scanwizard.o obj/channelscan_sm.o obj/channelscanner.o obj/channelscanner_gui.o obj/channelscanner_gui_scan_pane.o obj/channelscanner_cli.o obj/frequencytablesetting.o obj/inputselectorsetting.o obj/multiplexsetting.o obj/paneanalog.o obj/scanmonitor.o obj/scanwizardconfig.o obj/externrecscanner.o obj/eithelper.o obj/eitscanner.o obj/eitfixup.o obj/eitcache.o obj/programdata.o obj/tv_rec.o obj/recordingquality.o obj/recorderbase.o obj/DeviceReadBuffer.o obj/dtvrecorder.o obj/importrecorder.o obj/RTjpegN.o obj/audioinput.o obj/audioinputalsa.o obj/audioinputoss.o obj/v4lrecorder.o obj/v4l2util.o obj/v4lchannel.o obj/analogsignalmonitor.o obj/v4l2encrecorder.o obj/v4l2encstreamhandler.o obj/v4l2encsignalmonitor.o obj/mythv4l2m2mcontext.o obj/firewirechannel.o obj/firewirerecorder.o obj/firewiresignalmonitor.o obj/firewiredevice.o obj/avcinfo.o obj/linuxfirewiredevice.o obj/linuxavcinfo.o obj/cetonrtsp.o obj/iptvchannel.o obj/iptvrecorder.o obj/iptvsignalmonitor.o obj/iptvstreamhandler.o obj/streamhandler.o obj/packetbuffer.o obj/rtppacketbuffer.o obj/httptsstreamhandler.o obj/hlsstreamhandler.o obj/HLSPlaylistWorker.o obj/HLSReader.o obj/HLSSegment.o obj/HLSStream.o obj/HLSStreamWorker.o obj/vboxutils.o obj/vboxchannelfetcher.o obj/mpegrecorder.o obj/ExternalChannel.o obj/ExternalRecChannelFetcher.o obj/ExternalRecorder.o obj/ExternalStreamHandler.o obj/ExternalSignalMonitor.o obj/dvbtypes.o obj/dvbchannel.o obj/dvbsignalmonitor.o obj/dvbcam.o obj/dvbrecorder.o obj/dvbstreamhandler.o obj/dvbci.o obj/moc_jobqueue.o obj/moc_recordingprofile.o obj/moc_videosource.o obj/moc_playgroup.o obj/moc_channelsettings.o obj/moc_previewgenerator.o obj/moc_previewgeneratorqueue.o obj/moc_transporteditor.o obj/moc_mythsystemevent.o obj/moc_diseqcsettings.o obj/moc_profilegroup.o obj/moc_tv_play.o obj/moc_tv_play_win.o obj/moc_netstream.o obj/moc_osd.o obj/moc_videooutwindow.o obj/moc_videocolourspace.o obj/moc_mythopenglvideo.o obj/moc_mythopenglinterop.o obj/moc_mythopengltonemap.o obj/moc_mythvaapiglxinterop.o obj/moc_mythairplayserver.o obj/moc_mythraopdevice.o obj/moc_mythraopconnection.o obj/moc_mhegic.o obj/moc_scanwizard.o obj/moc_channelscanner_gui.o obj/moc_channelscanner_gui_scan_pane.o obj/moc_inputselectorsetting.o obj/moc_multiplexsetting.o obj/moc_paneatsc.o obj/moc_panedvbutilsimport.o obj/moc_scanmonitor.o obj/moc_scanwizardconfig.o obj/moc_cetonrtsp.o obj/moc_iptvchannel.o obj/moc_iptvstreamhandler.o obj/moc_httptsstreamhandler.o  -L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib -L../../external/libmythdvdnav -lmythdvdnav-32 -L../../external/libudfread -lmythudfread-32 -lva-glx -L../libmyth -L../../external/FFmpeg/libswresample -lmythswresample -L../../external/FFmpeg/libavutil -L../../external/FFmpeg/libavcodec -L../../external/FFmpeg/libavformat -L../../external/FFmpeg/libswscale -L../../external/FFmpeg/libpostproc -L../../external/FFmpeg/libavfilter -L../libmythui -L../libmythupnp -L../libmythbase -L../libmythservicecontracts -lmyth-32 -lmythswscale -lmythavformat -lmythavcodec -lmythavutil -lmythpostproc -lmythavfilter -lmythui-32 -lmythupnp-32 -lmythbase-32 -lmythservicecontracts-32 -L../libmythfreemheg -lmythfreemheg-32 -llzo2 -lXext -lXinerama -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -ldns_sd -lcrypto -lass -lEGL -lva-x11 -lX11 -lva-drm -lva -lasound -lfreetype -ldrm -lxml2 -lm -lz -lbluray -pthread -lsamplerate -lraw1394 -liec61883 -lavc1394 -lrom1394 -ldl -lpthread /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Widgets.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Network.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Xml.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Sql.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so -lGLESv2
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: .//../../../work/build_main.d/gcc-9.3.0/configure --prefix=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr --exec_prefix=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr --bindir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/bin --sbindir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec --datadir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/share --sysconfdir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/etc --sharedstatedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/share --localstatedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/var --libdir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --infodir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/info --includedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --oldincludedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --mandir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/share/man --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-local-prefix=/usr --enable-plugin --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-libatommic --enable-libgomp --enable-gold --enable-ld --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --disable-libada --disable-libssp --enable-lto --disable-multilib --enable-nls --enable-decimal-float --enable-shared --enable-host-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-mpc-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-mpc-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-mpfr-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-mpfr-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-gmp-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-gmp-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-isl-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-isl-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-libelf-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-libelf-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-sysroot=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (GCC)
COMPILER_PATH=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/../../../../armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/../../../../armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/lib/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/lib/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared' '-o' 'libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0' '-L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib' '-L../../external/libmythdvdnav' '-L../../external/libudfread' '-L../libmyth' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libswresample' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavutil' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavcodec' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavformat' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libswscale' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libpostproc' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavfilter' '-L../libmythui' '-L../libmythupnp' '-L../libmythbase' '-L../libmythservicecontracts' '-L../libmythfreemheg' '-pthread' '-shared-libgcc' '-mcpu=arm10tdmi' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv5t'
 /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/collect2 -plugin /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccUX1bUc.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main --eh-frame-hdr -shared -X -m armelf_linux_eabi -o libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0 /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/crti.o /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/crtbeginS.o -L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib -L../../external/libmythdvdnav -L../../external/libudfread -L../libmyth -L../../external/FFmpeg/libswresample -L../../external/FFmpeg/libavutil -L../../external/FFmpeg/libavcodec -L../../external/FFmpeg/libavformat -L../../external/FFmpeg/libswscale -L../../external/FFmpeg/libpostproc -L../../external/FFmpeg/libavfilter -L../libmythui -L../libmythupnp -L../libmythbase -L../libmythservicecontracts -L../libmythfreemheg -L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0 -L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/../../../../armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/lib -L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/lib -L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib -O1 -rpath /usr/lib/qt5/lib -rpath /usr/lib/qt5/lib -soname libmythtv-32.so.32 obj/cc.o obj/vbi.o obj/lang.o obj/recordinginfo.o obj/dbcheck.o obj/videodbcheck.o obj/httplivestreambuffer.o obj/m3u.o obj/profilegroup.o obj/tv_play.o obj/mythplayer.o obj/audioplayer.o obj/mythccextractorplayer.o obj/teletextextractorreader.o obj/playercontext.o obj/tv_play_win.o obj/deletemap.o obj/mythcommflagplayer.o obj/commbreakmap.o obj/tvbrowsehelper.o obj/netstream.o obj/mythiowrapper.o obj/textsubtitleparser.o obj/xine_demux_sputext.o obj/decoderbase.o obj/nuppeldecoder.o obj/avformatdecoder.o obj/privatedecoder.o obj/ifs_display.o obj/lines.o obj/surf3d.o obj/zoom_filter_mmx.o obj/channelscanner_gui_scan_pane.o obj/channelscanner_cli.o obj/frequencytablesetting.o obj/inputselectorsetting.o obj/multiplexsetting.o obj/paneanalog.o obj/scanmonitor.o obj/scanwizardconfig.o obj/externrecscanner.o obj/eithelper.o obj/eitscanner.o obj/eitfixup.o obj/eitcache.o obj/programdata.o obj/tv_rec.o obj/recordingquality.o obj/recorderbase.o obj/DeviceReadBuffer.o obj/dtvrecorder.o obj/importrecorder.o obj/RTjpegN.o obj/audioinput.o obj/audioinputalsa.o obj/audioinputoss.o obj/v4lrecorder.o obj/v4l2util.o obj/v4lchannel.o obj/analogsignalmonitor.o obj/v4l2encrecorder.o obj/v4l2encstreamhandler.o obj/v4l2encsignalmonitor.o obj/mythv4l2m2mcontext.o obj/firewirechannel.o obj/firewirerecorder.o obj/firewiresignalmonitor.o obj/firewiredevice.o obj/avcinfo.o obj/linuxfirewiredevice.o obj/linuxavcinfo.o obj/cetonrtsp.o obj/iptvchannel.o obj/iptvrecorder.o obj/iptvsignalmonitor.o obj/iptvstreamhandler.o obj/streamhandler.o obj/packetbuffer.o obj/rtppacketbuffer.o obj/httptsstreamhandler.o obj/hlsstreamhandler.o obj/HLSPlaylistWorker.o obj/HLSReader.o obj/HLSSegment.o obj/HLSStream.o obj/HLSStreamWorker.o obj/vboxutils.o obj/vboxchannelfetcher.o obj/mpegrecorder.o obj/ExternalChannel.o obj/ExternalRecChannelFetcher.o obj/ExternalRecorder.o obj/ExternalStreamHandler.o obj/ExternalSignalMonitor.o obj/dvbtypes.o obj/dvbchannel.o obj/dvbsignalmonitor.o obj/dvbcam.o obj/dvbrecorder.o obj/dvbstreamhandler.o obj/dvbci.o obj/moc_jobqueue.o obj/moc_recordingprofile.o obj/moc_videosource.o obj/moc_playgroup.o obj/moc_channelsettings.o obj/moc_previewgenerator.o obj/moc_previewgeneratorqueue.o obj/moc_transporteditor.o obj/moc_mythsystemevent.o obj/moc_diseqcsettings.o obj/moc_profilegroup.o obj/moc_tv_play.o obj/moc_tv_play_win.o obj/moc_netstream.o obj/moc_osd.o obj/moc_videooutwindow.o obj/moc_videocolourspace.o obj/moc_mythopenglvideo.o obj/moc_mythopenglinterop.o obj/moc_mythopengltonemap.o obj/moc_mythvaapiglxinterop.o obj/moc_mythairplayserver.o obj/moc_mythraopdevice.o obj/moc_mythraopconnection.o obj/moc_mhegic.o obj/moc_scanwizard.o obj/moc_channelscanner_gui.o obj/moc_channelscanner_gui_scan_pane.o obj/moc_inputselectorsetting.o obj/moc_multiplexsetting.o obj/moc_paneatsc.o obj/moc_panedvbutilsimport.o obj/moc_scanmonitor.o obj/moc_scanwizardconfig.o obj/moc_cetonrtsp.o obj/moc_iptvchannel.o obj/moc_iptvstreamhandler.o obj/moc_httptsstreamhandler.o -lmythdvdnav-32 -lmythudfread-32 -lva-glx -lmythswresample -lmyth-32 -lmythswscale -lmythavformat -lmythavcodec -lmythavutil -lmythpostproc -lmythavfilter -lmythui-32 -lmythupnp-32 -lmythbase-32 -lmythservicecontracts-32 -lmythfreemheg-32 -llzo2 -lXext -lXinerama -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -ldns_sd -lcrypto -lass -lEGL -lva-x11 -lX11 -lva-drm -lva -lasound -lfreetype -ldrm -lxml2 -lz -lbluray -lsamplerate -lraw1394 -liec61883 -lavc1394 -lrom1394 -ldl -lpthread /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Widgets.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Network.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Xml.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Sql.so /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so -lGLESv2 -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/crtendS.o /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/crtn.o
/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/lto-wrapper -fresolution=/tmp/ccUX1bUc.res -flinker-output=dyn /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/liblzo2.a@0x93a84 /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/liblzo2.a@0xdd748
armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf-g++ @/tmp/ccBzlLps
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf-g++
Target: armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: .//../../../work/build_main.d/gcc-9.3.0/configure --prefix=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr --exec_prefix=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr --bindir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/bin --sbindir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec --datadir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/share --sysconfdir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/etc --sharedstatedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/share --localstatedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/var --libdir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --infodir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/info --includedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --oldincludedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --mandir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/share/man --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-local-prefix=/usr --enable-plugin --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-libatommic --enable-libgomp --enable-gold --enable-ld --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --disable-libada --disable-libssp --enable-lto --disable-multilib --enable-nls --enable-decimal-float --enable-shared --enable-host-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-mpc-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-mpc-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-mpfr-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-mpfr-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-gmp-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-gmp-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-isl-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-isl-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-libelf-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-libelf-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-sysroot=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-fno-openmp' '-fno-openacc' '-fno-pie' '-mtune=cortex-a7' '-mfloat-abi=softfp' '-mfpu=neon-vfpv4' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-O2' '-v' '-shared' '-L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib' '-L../../external/libmythdvdnav' '-L../../external/libudfread' '-L../libmyth' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libswresample' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavutil' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavcodec' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavformat' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libswscale' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libpostproc' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavfilter' '-L../libmythui' '-L../libmythupnp' '-L../libmythbase' '-L../libmythservicecontracts' '-L../libmythfreemheg' '-pthread' '-shared-libgcc' '-mcpu=arm10tdmi' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm'  '-dumpdir' './' '-dumpbase' 'libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.wpa' '-fltrans-output-list=/tmp/libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.bfgQHe.ltrans.out' '-fwpa' '-fresolution=/tmp/ccUX1bUc.res' '-flinker-output=dyn' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv5t'
 /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/lto1 -quiet -dumpdir ./ -dumpbase libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.wpa -mtune=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mtls-dialect=gnu -mcpu=arm10tdmi -mtls-dialect=gnu -marm -march=armv5t -auxbase liblzo2 -O2 -version -fno-openmp -fno-openacc -fno-pie -fltrans-output-list=/tmp/libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.bfgQHe.ltrans.out -fwpa -fresolution=/tmp/ccUX1bUc.res -flinker-output=dyn @/tmp/cckNBYDe
GNU GIMPLE (GCC) version 9.3.0 (armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
GNU GIMPLE (GCC) version 9.3.0 (armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
COMPILER_PATH=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/../../../../armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/bin/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/../../../../armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/../../../../armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/lib/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/lib/:/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-fno-openmp' '-fno-openacc' '-fno-pie' '-mtune=cortex-a7' '-mfloat-abi=softfp' '-mfpu=neon-vfpv4' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-O2' '-v' '-shared' '-L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib' '-L../../external/libmythdvdnav' '-L../../external/libudfread' '-L../libmyth' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libswresample' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavutil' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavcodec' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavformat' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libswscale' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libpostproc' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavfilter' '-L../libmythui' '-L../libmythupnp' '-L../libmythbase' '-L../libmythservicecontracts' '-L../libmythfreemheg' '-pthread' '-shared-libgcc' '-mcpu=arm10tdmi' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm'  '-dumpdir' './' '-dumpbase' 'libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.wpa' '-fltrans-output-list=/tmp/libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.bfgQHe.ltrans.out' '-fwpa' '-fresolution=/tmp/ccUX1bUc.res' '-flinker-output=dyn' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv5t'
armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf-g++ @/tmp/ccKCtvMG
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf-g++
Target: armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: .//../../../work/build_main.d/gcc-9.3.0/configure --prefix=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr --exec_prefix=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr --bindir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/bin --sbindir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec --datadir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/share --sysconfdir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/etc --sharedstatedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/share --localstatedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/var --libdir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --infodir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/info --includedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --oldincludedir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --mandir=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/share/man --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-local-prefix=/usr --enable-plugin --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-libatommic --enable-libgomp --enable-gold --enable-ld --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --disable-libada --disable-libssp --enable-lto --disable-multilib --enable-nls --enable-decimal-float --enable-shared --enable-host-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-mpc-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-mpc-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-mpfr-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-mpfr-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-gmp-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-gmp-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-isl-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-isl-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-libelf-include=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/include --with-libelf-lib=//home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib --with-sysroot=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-fno-openmp' '-fno-openacc' '-fno-pie' '-mtune=cortex-a7' '-mfloat-abi=softfp' '-mfpu=neon-vfpv4' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-O2' '-v' '-shared' '-L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib' '-L../../external/libmythdvdnav' '-L../../external/libudfread' '-L../libmyth' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libswresample' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavutil' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavcodec' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavformat' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libswscale' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libpostproc' '-L../../external/FFmpeg/libavfilter' '-L../libmythui' '-L../libmythupnp' '-L../libmythbase' '-L../libmythservicecontracts' '-L../libmythfreemheg' '-pthread' '-shared-libgcc' '-mcpu=arm10tdmi' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm'  '-dumpdir' './' '-dumpbase' 'libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.ltrans0' '-fltrans' '-o' '/tmp/libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.bfgQHe.ltrans0.ltrans.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv5t'
 /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/libexec/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/lto1 -quiet -dumpdir ./ -dumpbase libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.ltrans0 -mtune=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mtls-dialect=gnu -mcpu=arm10tdmi -mtls-dialect=gnu -marm -march=armv5t -auxbase-strip /tmp/libmythtv-32.so.32.0.0.bfgQHe.ltrans0.ltrans.o -O2 -version -fno-openmp -fno-openacc -fno-pie -fltrans @/tmp/ccD9DwUp -o /tmp/ccdmhKhE.s
GNU GIMPLE (GCC) version 9.3.0 (armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
GNU GIMPLE (GCC) version 9.3.0 (armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
In function ‘u2p’:
lto1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf-g++ returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/9.3.0/../../../../armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `how to move forward` 1. Remove some code from your project, for example from `main()`. 2. See if it compilers. 3. Repeat until it compiles. Also: add the verbose option to g++ and see what it is doing and when and which linker it is calling (and post the output here). Why `-Wl,-O1` and not just `-O1`? Generally, remove code until you find the _minimal_ [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: Kamil, sure we can reduce code and see... but maybe more effective will be to understand why segfault is in lto_wraper when lto is disabled? I see 3 opts: a\in real lto is enabled; b\lto is disabled but gcc errantly still goes with it; c\it is normal gcc runs lto_wrapper even without lto. Let first eliminate a\. When b\ or c\ left: probably more effective will be to find link params allowing to link ok on armv7?. If this fails - I can fill bug. rep.  - but it is last resort as holds dev.process. I think mods. in src. because we failing on 1 from 3 targets by tool ver. bug isn't optimal right?

Comment: Exactly - run `gcc -v` and see which linker does it call and trace the executable. (I don't remember, I think it's `-v` option to make it verbose).

Answer (score 0):

Well - partial explanation/solution: my toolchain seems to be configured with LTO enabled by default. I'm not passing explicitly `-fno-lto` to turn it off at app. compilation. Adding this solves issue....